# Autoresponder for MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

What's the simplest/proper way to create an autoresponder for MS Teams via the Teams SDK?  I'm constantly getting "Hi" messages from colleagues at work who like to see if I'm at my screen before asking a question.

Them: "Hi"

Me: "Hi"

Them: "I have a question...."

I've looked at some of the Bot tutorials but I'm not looking to create an autonomous bot that people can have conversations with, but rather something that can monitor my conversations and respond "creatively" on my behalf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported currently. We have raised a feature request to have a Graph API to send message on 1:1 chat.